# Error occur when run example python-telegram-bot code

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm running one of the sample python-telegram-bot, but I get the following error:

Error:

```
import telegram

  File "C:\Users\Ramin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\python_telegram_bot-12.0.0b1-py3.6.egg\telegram\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\python_telegram_bot-12.0.0b1-py3.6.egg\telegram\bot.py", line 43, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\python_telegram_bot-12.0.0b1-py3.6.egg\telegram\utils\request.py", line 35, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3'
```

Comment: Have you installed the telegram package?

Comment: Yes , i installed it

Comment: When import telegram , No module named 'telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3 error occur

Comment: So you did `pip3 install telegram`?

Comment: i installed it with python 3

Answer (score 0):

ptb_urllib3 is a submodule of telegram-bot you can initialize it by doing the following:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```